# How to adjust PySpark shell log level?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Currently I got an NullPointException. I have no idea how to fix it. 
Just wondering if I can adjust the Python log level and see if I can get more information from that. Question: how can I adjust the log level for PySpark?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/02/28 16:52:22 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
17/02/28 16:52:22 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-2
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.close(ExternalShuffleClient.java:152)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1231)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1768)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1230)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1767)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(pyFiles=add_files)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 172, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 235, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1064, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
:
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom log4j file with more detailed logging level for the gateway, for example:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer=DEBUG
```

Then use it in pyspark command in the following way:

```
./bin/pyspark --driver-java-options '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-debug.properties'
```

Comment: after investigate the source code, 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a36a76ac43c36a3b897a748bd9f138b629dbc684/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py
the 'java gateway' is something like "./bin/spark-submit --conf xxkey=xxvalue --conf xxxkey=xxxvalue pyspark-shell". Could you help clarify how the parameter '--driver-java-options' passed into the underneath './bin/spark-submit'? thanks.

Comment: It is rewritten to `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`. See `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']` in pyspark shell.